# How do I use the regular pattern operator {m,n} in grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have a text file, from which I need to select only those lines, which include the string "tt". So I tried this on the command line:

```
grep "t{2}" textfile
```

Allthough I know the textfile contains words like "rotten" "litter"
the grep command shows no lines, the exit status however is 1.

I tried another regular pattern:

```
grep "a.*x" textfile
```

for this one it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) uses [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06), you need to escape the braces to make grep match multiple characters:

```
grep 't\{2\}' textfile
```

Alternatively, you can use the `-E` option (or [-P option for GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs), which uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/)) making `grep` use [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), which can use braces without escaping them:

```
grep -E 't{2}'
```

Comment: Or you could use `egrep`, which is equivalent to `grep -E` but a bit easier to type.

Comment: You should call `grep -E` directly, calling `egrep` is  deprecated, it is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

Comment: The `-P` is not full-fledged, so for source code searches, one could use `ack` (to get full PCRE, as its written in `Perl`), or its faster clone `ag`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the braces:

```
grep 't\{2\}' textfile
```

Otherwise `{` and `}` are treated as literal characters.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `-E` (`--extended-regexp`) or `-P` (`--perl-regexp`) option (with GNU grep).

According to the GNU grep(1) man page about *Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions*, i.e. if you choose not to use these options:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).